# Problema has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Testou tendo problema com relação entre tabelas Departamento e Funcionario

Esta retornando 2 erro: 
-"EntityType 'Funcionario' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType." 
-Funcionarios' is based on type 'Funcionario' that has no keys defined.
E se eu colocar [Key] em ambas  continua mesma coisa, com msg "Falha em ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN porque a coluna 'FuncionnarioID' não existe na tabela 'Funcionario'." Sendo que ela tem sim o campo FuncionnarioID,

Departamento:

```
    public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }

    public string DEPARTAMENTO_NOME { get; set; }

    public string DEPARTAMENTO_SALA { get; set; }


    public string ANDAR { get; set; }
```

Funcionario:

```
        public int FuncionnarioID { get; set; }

    public string FUNCIONARIO_EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string FUNCIONARIO_NOME { get; set; }
    public string FUNCIONARIO_CIDADE { get; set; }

    public string FUNCIONARIO_ENDERECO { get; set; }


    public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }


    [ ForeignKey("DepartamentoID")]
    public virtual  Departamento Departamento { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique mais uma vez se realmente os nomes estão batendo, se caso estiverem corretos, faça o seguinte, em cima da sua `Propriedade Primary Key` Adiciona o `Data Annotation [Key]` da seguinte forma:

Departamento:

```
[Key]
public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }

public string DEPARTAMENTO_NOME { get; set; }

public string DEPARTAMENTO_SALA { get; set; }

public string ANDAR { get; set; }
```

Funcionario:

```
   [Key]
   public int FuncionnarioID { get; set; }

   public string FUNCIONARIO_EMAIL { get; set; }

   public string FUNCIONARIO_NOME { get; set; }

   public string FUNCIONARIO_CIDADE { get; set; }

   public string FUNCIONARIO_ENDERECO { get; set; }

   public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }

   [ ForeignKey("DepartamentoID")]
   public virtual  Departamento Departamento { get; set; }
```

Te aconselho a não usar os nomes de `Propriedades` dessa forma `NOME_PROPRIEDADE` porque assim é a nomenclatura para `Constantes` e isso pode te atrapalhar futuramente, talvez seja melhor você utilizar dessa forma:

Departamento:

```
[Key]
public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }

[Column("DEPARTAMENTO_NOME")]
public string  DepartamentoNome { get; set; }

[Column("DEPARTAMENTO_SALA")]
public string  DepartamentoSala { get; set; }

[Column("ANDAR")]
public string Andar { get; set; }
```

Isso te ajudará no futuro, se quiser conhecer um pouco mais sobre isso, tem um link bem simples explicando como funciona e alguns exemplos: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx